# How to throw cancellation exception in an async for each implementation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-core, cancellationtokensource

I have a custom async for each implementation that is defined and used as follows:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int partitionCount, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(partitionCount)
        select Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            using (partition)
            {
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                {
                    await body(partition.Current).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        })
    );
}
```

...

```
List<long> ids = new List...

await ids.ForEachAsync(8,
    async (id) =>
    {
        await myTask(id);
    }
);
```

This works great, but now I need to modify this to allow for a cancellation token to be passed in. I have tried something as simple as this:

```
List<long> ids = new List...

await ids.ForEachAsync(8,
    async (id) =>
    {
        myToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await myTask(id);
    }
);
```

But this fails ungracefully. Rather than an `OperationCanceledException` bubbling up, as I would have expected, I am receiving an exception that is being thrown by one of the threads as a result of the cancellation. I have also tried passing the token into the async extension method but that didn't seem to work either. Can someone please provide guidance on how this should be done? Thanks.

Comment: Would you please narrow down your question by excluding the part that "works great" and focusing just on a problematic part with added clarity on the issue, namely: what is expected and what did you get? Thanks and regards,

Comment: Did you use [Task.Run( Action , CancellationToken)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) when you tried to inject the CancellationToken into the extension method?

Comment: @AlexBell The part that works great is the relevant code that I am trying to modify. I will edit my post to be more explicit however. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Fildor Definitely not. I will give that a shot.

Comment: Where do you catch the exception?

Comment: What do you intend by "ungracefully"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the exception to bubble up you need to pass the token in to the `Task.Run` it will just take a small modification to your code.

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int partitionCount, Func<T, Task> body, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(partitionCount)
        select Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            using (partition)
            {
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                {
                    await body(partition.Current).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }, token) //token passed in
    );
}
```

used like

```
await ids.ForEachAsync(8,
    async (id) =>
    {
        myToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await myTask(id);
    },
    myToken //token passed in
);
```

Comment: that token passed to `Task.Run` will only prevent `Task.Run` from starting a task. It won't cancel it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado it also has the affect of causing the task to enter the Canceled state if a OperationCanceledException was thrown using the same Cancelation Token that was passed in, which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: run this `using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(100)) { await Task.Run(async ()=> await Task.Delay(1000), cts.Token); }` and this `using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(100)) { await Task.Run(async ()=> await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token), cts.Token); }` and explain the difference.

Comment: @PauloMorgado That difference is not what I am talking about, what I am talking about is why [this program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v91K1M) outputs canceled in one version and faulted in the other.